# How are static data and method details stored in C++

Tags: c++, layout, object

I have a very basic doubt, In C++ does there exist a data structure for each Type which stores static data and methods defined by that type, similar to the data structure that exists in .NET for every Type.

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no such thing (called reflection) in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dark and oli